# Prolog: Can you make a predicate behave differently depending on whether a value is ground or not?

Tags: prolog, logical-purity

I have a somewhat complex predicate with four arguments that need to work when both the first and last arguments are ground/not ground, not ground/ground or ground/ground, and the second and third arguments are ground.

i.e. predicate(A,B,C,D).

I can't provide my actual code since it is part of an assignment.

I have it mostly working, but am receiving instantiation errors when A is not ground, but D is. However, I have singled out a line of code that is causing issues. When I change the goal order of the predicate, it works when D is ground and A is not, but in doing so, it no longer works for when A is ground and D is  not. I'm not sure there is a way around this.

Is there a way to use both lines of code so that if the A is ground for instance it will use the first line, but if A is not ground, it will use the second, and ignore the first? And vice versa.

Comment: `var(A)` and `nonvar(A)` probably do what you want

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't come across those in my course yet, but they did the trick!

Comment: Using `var/1` for such purpose very often leads to difficulties.  Use either `ground/1` or `nonvar/1`. Depending on what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that, **but**, almost invariably, you will break the declarative semantics of your programs *if* you do that.

Consider a simple example to see how such a non-monotonic and extra-logical predicate already breaks basic assumptions and typical declarative properties of well-known predicates, like commutativity of conjunction:

```
?- ground(X), X = a.
false.
```

But, if we simply exchange the goals by commutativity of conjunction, we get a *different* answer:

```
?- X = a, ground(X).
X = a.
```

For this reason, such meta-logical predicates are best avoided, especially if you are just beginning to learn the language.

Instead, better stay in the pure and monotonic subset of Prolog. Use *constraints* like `dif/2` and CLP(FD) to make your programs usable in all directions, increasing generality and ease of understanding.

See [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity), [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif) and [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) for more information.